# AVFoundation AVAssetExportSession produces a blank video when trying to flip the video with layer instruction

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am trying to flip a video the right way up using the AVFoundation framework. For some reason the code below is producing a blank video every time.

I have noticed that when I do not apply the videoComposition setting for the AVAssetExportSession, it does pass the video through (its visible and playable in the Photo LIbrary) but it is not flipped as the layer instruction is not applied. So I assumed that the issue is in the layer instruction being passed into the composition, but it is properly set up. What am I missing, or not seeing?

Here is the code:

```
    NSURL *assetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVAsset *movieAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];
    NSLog(@"Asset: %0.1f",CMTimeGetSeconds(movieAsset.duration));
    NSLog(@"Asset Preferred Transform %@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(movieAsset.preferredTransform));



    //Output Composition
    AVMutableComposition *outputComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [outputComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                           preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, movieAsset.duration)
                        ofTrack:[[movieAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                         atTime:kCMTimeZero
                          error:nil];
    [videoTrack setPreferredTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videoLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
    [videoLayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *videoInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    videoInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, movieAsset.duration);
    videoInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videoLayerInstruction, nil];


    AVMutableVideoComposition *outputVideoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    outputVideoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videoInstruction, nil];
    outputVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    outputVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(480, 640);


    //Export
    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:outputComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality] ;
    exporter.videoComposition = outputVideoComposition;
    NSString *newPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.filePath stringByAppendingString:@"-fb.mov"]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:newPath error:nil];
    exporter.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath];
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    NSLog(@"Starting export");



    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Video exported");
            NSLog(@"%@", newPath);
            NSURL *newAssetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath];
            AVAsset *newMovieAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:newAssetURL];
            NSLog(@"New Asset %@",newMovieAsset);
            NSLog(@"New Asset Duration: %0.1f",CMTimeGetSeconds(newMovieAsset.duration));
            NSLog(@"New Asset Preferred Transform %@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(newMovieAsset.preferredTransform));


            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(newPath, nil, nil, nil);}}];
```

Answer (score 2):

the render size  which you are giving to the outputVideoComposition is not correct. it should be according to the iphone screen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it is rotating the video out of exporting frame. Thing of the rotation anchor being in the top left hand corner.

To fix, apply another transformation, something like this:

CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(exportingVideoWidth, exportingVideoHeight);

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.